# What was the movie about AI?

Tags: story-identification

Have a vague memory of an American film, possibly from the 90's about computers that became aware. Might have had some vague horror elements to it and the 'computers' were like shiny cubes.

I thought it was called Chronos but can't find anything under that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! This question is very vague as it stands - can you remember any more details at all about this film? Please read [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking story-ID questions; some of the questions there may help to trigger your memory of some extra detail.

Comment: Is it possible you're thinking of the movie [Kronos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronos_(film))? It's from 1957 and the antagonist is an alien robot rather than a human-made computer that becomes self-aware, but as mentioned in [this review](http://www.1000misspenthours.com/reviews/reviewsh-m/kronos1957.htm), the robot looks like "a pair of black metal cubes stacked on top of each other, separated by a stout chrome cylinder". So even though the movie doesn't fit very well there's enough similarities I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: The movie Demon Seed had robots built up of shiny metal triangular blocks, and it does have some horror elements to it.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Seed

Comment: Thanks all, yes was extremely vague, and yes it was Demon Seed! Will have to watch it again. Thanks so much, had been bugging me for a while.

Comment: That duplicate is for the book, not the movie. I guess that’s close enough...

Answer (score 2):

The movie *[Demon Seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Seed)* had robots built up of shiny metal triangular blocks, and it does have some horror elements to it.

[image: Movie Poster]

Here is [a clip that includes the robot](https://youtube.com/ugr-QLXyVWM?t=5m).